How did this new user create a tag?
As I was cruising over the front page of questions, I noticed this question where there was a tag nonlinear initially, before it was edited to be removed. There was only edit before which didn’t change the tags. So, the OP must have created the tag. But, he/she is a new contributor. As per the help centre, tag creation privileges are awarded at $1000$ reputation points. So, how did this happen?

Looking at the posts that had the tag (nonlinear), there were at least two:

Cauchy problem of nonlinear PDE with a weird condition (id=5007570)
Solving the coupled Nonlinear System in Stability analysis using Lyapunov function (id=5007577: This is the one you link to.)

The question with the lower id was posted sooner. The timestamps are 2024-12-05 14:30:09Z and 2024-12-05 14:41:23Z.
So the tag was probably created here by a user who has more than 2000 reputation points.

One could also check using SEDE where a specific tag was created and removed. But the data in SEDE are only once a week, so this new posts are not shown there. (And the post you linked in the question is very likely to be deleted - so after that, that post will not be shown in these queries. SEDE contains some data about deleted posts, but not PostHistory.)

How did you find the other question? When I clicked on the tag, I couldn't see any,

Naturally, since the tag was removed from both question, they are not shown under this tag now. As you can see from the first link in my post, I noticed that the tag was created and make a note about that in the Tagging chatroom - including the posts which had that tag at the time. (Of course, it is possible that the tag was actually created in yet another post - but not very likely.)
